# Cmake error when trying to install cura through yay

Tags: cmake, archlinux

I get this error when using `yay -S cura` on archlinux

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findstandardprojectsettings.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH
  this project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided
  by "standardprojectsettings", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "standardprojectsettings" with any of the following names:

    standardprojectsettingsConfig.cmake
    standardprojectsettings-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "standardprojectsettings" to
  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "standardprojectsettings_DIR" to a directory
  containing one of the above files.  If "standardprojectsettings" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
    Aborting...
 -> error making: libarcus-git-exit status 4
==> Making package: cura 5.3.0-1 (Wed 08 Nov 2023 12:12:33 PM CST)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Missing dependencies:
  -> uranium
  -> curaengine
==> Checking buildtime dependencies...
==> ERROR: Could not resolve all dependencies.
 -> error making: cura-exit status 8
 -> Failed to install the following packages. Manual intervention is required:
curaengine - exit status 8
libarcus-git - exit status 4
cura - exit status 8
uranium - exit status 8
```

I seem to be able to install other packages using yay with no issues.

I have spent a lot of time googling phrases like `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4:`
and such, but I couldn't find anything helpful.

My system is up to date, I updated the mirrorlist yesterday and ran `sudo pacman -Syu` with no issues.

I have tried `yay -Syu` which runs without issue, but still doesn't help.

I don't know much about CMake, and I don't know what to do, can someone help?
I am happy to provide any extra information if needed.

Comment: Hi, that's no forum for that. Ask on reddit. So the error is about that it is not able to find "standardprojectsettings" software.  I see nothing on https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/cura . In source is only https://github.com/Ultimaker/libArcus/blame/main/CMakeLists.txt#L4 and I do not know what is "standardprojectsettings". Make sure you install all requirements as listed in https://github.com/Ultimaker/libArcus/tree/main#linux . For what is worth, I am getting the same error, no idea. You could also compile from source https://github.com/Ultimaker/Cura using conan, instead of cmake.

Comment: On Stack Overflow we do not put solution into a question post, and do not write "solved" in the title. You may write your own answer and provide a solution in it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer. Once an answer will be accepted, the question will get green mark.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you very much for letting me know, I have fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to install cura using `yay -S cura-bin` instead of `yay -S cura`